# How can I center the Border On Hover

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

How can I center the border on hover ?

```
.elementor-widget-nav-menu .elementor-nav-menu--main:not(.e--pointer-framed) .elementor-item:before, .elementor-widget-nav-menu .elementor-nav-menu--main:not(.e--pointer-framed) .elementor-item:after {
    background-color: #61ce70;
    width: 18%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I'm looking for 
[image]

Currently, I have

[image]

Comment: Add `right: 0` to the CSS above in question and it should work, not sure if this is the best that can be done.

Comment: Yes, this one also worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for whatever reason it is positioned absolute, not a great strategy. But sort solution ist set:

```
left: 41%
```

for this rule:

```
.elementor-75 .elementor-element.elementor-element-c3c42c8 .elementor-nav-menu--main:not(.e--pointer-framed) .elementor-item:before, .elementor-75 .elementor-element.elementor-element-c3c42c8 .elementor-nav-menu--main:not(.e--pointer-framed) .elementor-item:after
```

Comment: The position is set from the plugin. Thank you for your quick reply & solution.